# ksqlDB - How to set batch.size and linger.ms for producers to optimise compression

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, ksqldb

When configuring ksqlDB I can set the option [ksql.streams.producer.compression.type](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/server-configuration/#ksqlstreamsproducercompressiontype) which enables compression for ksqlDB's internal producers. Thus when I create a ksqlDB stream, it's output topic will be compressed with the selected compression type.

However, as far as I have understood the compression performance is heavily impacted by how much batching the producer does. Therefore, I wish to be able to configure the [batch.size](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#batch-size) and [linger.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_linger.ms) parameters for ksqlDB's producers. Does anyone know if and how these parameters can be set for ksqlDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matthias J Sax for answering my question on the Confluent Community Slack channel: https://app.slack.com/client/T47H7EWH0/threads?cdn_fallback=1

There is an info-box in the documentation.
That explains it pretty well:

[KSQL documentation info box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYtVF.png)

> The underlying producer and consumer clients in ksqlDB's server can be
> modified with any valid properties. Simply use the form
> ksql.streams.producer.xxx, ksql.streams.consumer.xxx to pass the
> property through. For example, ksql.streams.producer.compression.type
> sets the compression type on the producer.

Source: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/server-configuration/